# iOS sqlite transaction disk error

Tags: ios, sqlite, transactions

I got an ios app in C using SQLite : all my requests was working fine util i try to add some transaction for safer data update

What i m doing : 
BEGIN IMMEDIATE TRANSACTION;

DELETE FROM StoreItems where id IN (221,231,1850,1852,1854,4315,4387,4389);

INSERT INTO StoreItems ('id', 'title', 'description', 'type', 'args')select '221' as id, 'Super Coin' as title, 'Virtual currency' as description, 'consumable' as type, 'START_VALUE=500' as args union select '231','Vampiric sword','A sword with 10% life steal','durable','steal=1' union select '1850','Shield','Shield','consumable','' union select '1852','Mana potion','Mana potion','consumable','' union select '1854','Life potion','Life potion','consumable','' union select '4315','Sword of evil','Sword of evil','consumable','' union select '4387','Boots','Boots','durable','' union select '4389','Bonus XP x2','Bonus XP x2','consumable','';

COMMIT; //or ROLLBACK; if there is a issue

both request in the middle work if i remove the transaction, but with it, it throw me an error  : disk I/O error

Did i miss something ?

Answer (score 0):

I found how to fix the issue : i have replaced the INSERT by an INSERT OR REPLACE, but i still do not get why i have to do that.. (there is no UNIQUE constraint)